# Fetching results from database in PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I developed a simple upload photo and comment system. When I use for each, it repeats the image. E.g If there are 5 comments on a photo. It repeats the photo 5 times with the 5 different comments. Instead of one image for 5 comments.

I want 1 image with each comments. How do I get all the comments for each photo without repeating the photo?

I use PDO and here is the php code:

```
<?php
//This is for the images
$results = $connecDB->prepare("select image,caption,id from gallery order by id desc LIMIT $start, $limit ");
$results->execute(); 
$results = $results->fetchAll();

foreach($results as $results) {
    $pid=$results["id"];

    //This is for the comments
    $re= $connecDB->prepare("select * from comments  where pid = :pid order by id");
    $re->bindParam(':pid', $pid);
    $re->execute(); 

    foreach($re as $re) {
        $name=$re["name"];
        $comment=$re["comment"];
?>

<div class="item" id="item-<?php echo $results['id']?>">
    <p><img src="../upload/images/<?php echo $results['image']?>"  height="500px" width="500px"</p>
    <p><?php echo $results['caption']?></p>
    <div class="large-2 columns small-3"><font color="#3366ff"><?php echo $name?></font></div>
    <div class="large-10 columns"><p><?php echo $comment?></p></div>  
<?php}
}?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach your output here? Perhaps an image of the output ?

Comment: You can't do `foreach ($results as $results)`, as you're overwriting your initial `$results` variable. Should be something like `foreach ($results as $result)`, and then use `$result['id']`, etc. inside the block. Fix that issue and see what you're left with. (same with the `foreach($re as $re)` block...)

Comment: @Ibrahim You are not fetching data after executing the query for comments. You code looks fine you just need to fetchAll values as I mentioned in my answer

Comment: @Ibrahim as Sunsheel mentioned that you were looping everything inside foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were **looping** everything inside **inner** loop, try like this.

```
<?php
//This is for the images
$results = $connecDB->prepare("select image,caption,id from gallery order by id desc LIMIT $start, $limit ");
$results->execute(); 
$results = $results->fetchAll();

foreach($results as $results) {
    $pid=$results["id"];
?>
    <div class="item" id="item-<?php echo $results['id']?>">
        <p><img src="../upload/images/<?php echo $results['image']?>"  height="500px" width="500px" /></p>
        <p><?php echo $results['caption']?></p>
    <?php
        //This is for the comments
        $re= $connecDB->prepare("select * from comments  where pid = :pid order by id");
        $re->bindParam(':pid', $pid);
        $re->execute(); 

        foreach($re as $re) {
            $name=$re["name"];
            $comment=$re["comment"];
    ?>
    <div class="large-2 columns small-3"><font color="#3366ff"><?php echo $name?></font></div>
    <div class="large-10 columns"><p><?php echo $comment?></p></div>  
    <?php}?>
    </div>
<?php}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not getting the result in **$re** variable. You need to **fetchAll** data after executing the query. As well as you were looping everything in inner foreach.

```
foreach($results as $results) {
$pid=$results["id"];

//This is for the comments
$re= $connecDB->prepare("select * from comments  where pid = :pid order by id");
$re->bindParam(':pid', $pid);
$re->execute(); 
$comments = $re->fetchAll();

<div class="item" id="item-<?php echo $results['id']?>">
    <p><img src="../upload/images/<?php echo $results['image']?>"  height="500px" width="500px"</p>
    <p><?php echo $results['caption']?></p>
    <div class="large-2 columns small-3"><font color="#3366ff"><?php echo $name?></font></div>
  foreach($comments as $re) {
    $name=$re["name"];
    $comment=$re["comment"];
?>  
    <div class="large-10 columns"><p><?php echo $comment; ?></p></div>  
<?php}
}?>
```